# `GetThumbnailAsync` transparency issues

Tags: windows-runtime, uwp, png, transparency

I know there are a number of threads concerning "zomg png transparency gone when I create a thumbnail on UWP" but this is a bit more nuanced than that.

I realize the output of `GetThumbnailAsync` is a bitmap, generally without transparency support. I know that by default the background color used for transparent images converted to a bitmap under UWP is the background color of the application (which is a different problem altogether), but what I discovered is that when calling `GetThumbnailAsync` against icons with existing 32-bit transparency, this transparency is preserved.

However when `GetThumbnailAsync` is called against a PNG with transparency, the background is coerced to black. This rather sucks when the only non-transparent color in the PNG is black, because you just end up with an all-black blob.

Heres' a screenshot with 2 `Image` elements rendered, the source for each being a call to `GetThumbnailAsync()`. The first icon was called against an exe with a 32-bit icon w/ transparency, the second was against a 32-bit PNG w/ transparency:

[image: GetThumbnailAsync results, exe vs png]

This demonstrates that transparency is actually supported in the resulting bitmap images created by `GetThumbnailAsync()` and that the background color can actually be "transparent" and not "your application color." Yet for some reason the PNG thumbnails always lose their transparency. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: AFAIK, a image thumbnail with transparent background always adapts to background of container. Example is when you see the image in explorer, it will be white. So when you render thumbnail, it takes black since there is no container. This might be like throwing a stone in the dark but did you try setting the image background to transparent after rendering it?

Comment: @AVKNaidu but the first icon would suggest that is not the case, since it has a transparent background that is being filled in with the grey container background rather than black.

Comment: Yes but there is a Huge difference between ICO and PNG file structure. if my memory is correct. ICO is a collection of Small Images with Multiple depths and layers with scaling. PNG is not. However let me markup a simple Project and see if i can replicate your scenario.

Comment: @AVKNaidu I'm not denying the difference in the images source format; the issue is that both PNG and ICO support transparency, both are being converted to the same bitmap format, but one loses the transparency while the other doesn't. Yet WinRT/UWP supports transcoding of both while preserving transparency, so it's not clear why `GetThumbnailAsync` doesn't.

Comment: If I were to venture a guess - the thumbnails that Windows generates never preserve transparency. The likely reason that your ICO has transparency is that `GetThumbnailAsync()` would actually return the original image if it's resolution already matched requested thumbnail size requirements. The other thing worth checking is the pixel format you get for that thumbnail. I think XAML generally works with premultiplied alpha, while it's possibly the thumbnail has non-premultiplied alpha in which case you could be getting unexpected results for transparent pixels.

Answer (score 1):

I think this boils down to a "bug" in Windows 10, it would seem that transparency data is lost in general. Here's what happens when I drag the source file in Windows Explorer, which is a PNG w/ transparency and a black-only foreground:

[image: all black image]

The solution I just coded up (so pardon any oversights!) is to bypass `GetThumbnailAsync()` for transparent PNGs and generate my own PNG thumbnail that preserves the transparency:

```
public static class ThumbnailExtensions
{
    public static async Task<IRandomAccessStream> GetTransparentThumbnailAsync(this StorageFile file, ThumbnailMode mode, uint requestedSize, ThumbnailOptions options = ThumbnailOptions.None)
    {
        if (file.FileType.ToLower() == ".png")
        {
            //try to create a scaled-down version of the PNG with transparency
            using (var fstream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
            {
                var thumbnail = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
                var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(BitmapDecoder.PngDecoderId, fstream);
                var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateForTranscodingAsync(thumbnail, decoder);

                encoder.BitmapTransform.ScaledHeight = requestedSize;
                encoder.BitmapTransform.ScaledWidth = requestedSize;
                encoder.BitmapTransform.InterpolationMode = BitmapInterpolationMode.Fant;

                await encoder.FlushAsync();
                await thumbnail.FlushAsync();
                return thumbnail;
            }
        }

        return await file.GetThumbnailAsync(mode, requestedSize, options);
    }
}
```

The result isn't the prettiest (even `InterpolationMode.Fant` sucks; but there are Lanczos implementations for C# floating around somewhere), but it is transparent:

[image: transparency preserved]

The code above would need to be extended to support preserving the aspect ratio and padding or cropping images that are not 1:1 to fit.